# Editable fields with 'apply' and 'cancel' buttons (too much recursion)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recursion, contenteditable

I've got `h2` tag with the attribute `contenteditable="true"`. The goal is to make 'apply' button click by which makes `contenteditable="false"` and 'cancel' button which assigns initial `h2` text to that `h2`, basically clears last edit and also sets `contenteditable` to `"false"`. 
My codepen for this is https://codepen.io/utkapodsousom/pen/dJOMaB
I cannot figure out how to make those buttons work without bubbling and recursion.

Comment: I see from your codepen that you don't have any buttons, and trying to make it work with 'blur' and 'focus' events only. Can you please clarify the requirement a little more so that we can try to help? I have a working sample with buttons now, but not sure if that's what you want!

Comment: Buttons would appear only when a field is editable. The word 'yes' represents 'apply' btn and 'no' is 'cancel' accordingly. 'blur' and 'focus' events are there for making the editable field become non editable by clicking outside the field. But the buttons should be there too. I made them by adding `::before` and `::after` to the `[contenteditable="true"]` selector, but maybe there is better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to `too much recursion` problem is that in this piece of code I'm calling the function from within itself by writing `.focus` twice.

```
$('.editable').on('click focus', function(e) {
  $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
  $(this).focus();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```